# Advice on Setup

Tags: performance, installation, view

I started my first data analysis job a few months ago and I am in charge of a SQL database and then taking that data and creating dashboards within Power BI. Our SQL database is replicated from an online web portal we use for data entry. We do not add data ourselves to the database but instead the data is put into tables based on the data entered into the web portal. Since this database is replicated via another company, I created our own database that is connected via linked server. I have built many views to pull only the needed data from the initial database( did this to limit the amount of data sent to Power BI for performance). My view count is climbing and wondering in terms of performance, is this the best way forward. The highest row count of a view is 32,000 and the lowest is around 1000 rows.

Some of the views that I am writing end up joining 5-6 tables together due to the structure built by the data web portal company that controls the database.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create a Datawarehouse schema ( star schema ) keeping as principal, one star schema per domain. For example one for sales, one for subscriptions, one for purchase, etc. Use the logic of Datamarts.
Identify your dimensions and your facts and keep evolving that schema. You will find out that you will end up with a much fewer number of tables.
Your data are not that big so you can use whatever ETL strategy you like.
Truncate load or incrimental.